# Using a static class as an array of Objects

Tags: java, arrays, object, nullpointerexception

I'm a computer science student working on an assignment with the following instructions:

"Develop an application that will read an input text string and count the number of A’s, B’s, C’s, etc....you will create a Letter class that will hold the letter and number of occurrences and a LetterList class that can be a static array of Letter objects."

I'm having trouble figuring out exactly how to use my static class containing the array of Letter objects. I have my classes written as follows:

```
public class Letter {

    private char letter;
    private int count;

    //constructor and getters and setters omitted

    public void increment() {
        count++;
    }

    static class LetterList {

    private static final int MAX = 26;
    private static Letter[] list;
    private static int size = 0; //to prevent null pointer exception

    public LetterList() {
        list = new Letter[MAX];
    }

    public static int length() {
        return size;
    }

    public static void addLetter(Letter letter) {
        boolean added = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX && !added; i++) {
            if (list[i] != null) {
                //if the letter exists in the array increment the count
                if (letter.getLetter() == list[i].getLetter()) {
                    list[i].increment();
                    added = true;
                }
            } else {
                //if it doesn't exist add it
                list[i] = letter;
                added = true;
                size++;
            }
        }
    }

    public static Letter getElement(int idx) {
        return list[idx];
    }

    public static void clearList() {
        size = 0;
    }

  }

}
```

Since this class is static, is the constructor required? When I want to add elements to my Letter[] array in my LetterList class, what is the proper way? Would it be better to have my LetterList class on its own? I appreciate any help and thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't believe you would want the constructor in this case... simply at the top do `private static Letter[] list = new Letter[MAX];`. Therefore it is truly static because in order for your code to work right now you would need to call the constructor. If you want to add a letter to your `Letter[]` simply do... `LetterList.addLetter(....);`. In my opinion you should separate these two classes out.

Comment: Static class does not require a constructor. I think a `Map<String,Integer>` will serve your need better than array.

Comment: At this level I’d find it wise to follow the professor’s suggestions, in this case a static array of `Letter` objects (for production code I too would do something else, but leave that out for now).

Comment: Thank you all for taking the time to help. I'll be implementing your suggestions and submitting my assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since this class is static, is the constructor required?

No, it’s optional, but a constructor is not the best place to initialize static fields, so in this case you should leave it out. If that were me, I’d follow @3kings’ suggestion also because I find it more readable when the list is instantiated in the declaration. For the constructor, a still better option (though maybe slightly advanced) is a private constructor that does nothing. This will catch if someone some day tries to instatntiate the class (with `new`), which would be an error (or at least futile).

> When I want to add elements to my Letter[] array in my LetterList
>   class, what is the proper way?

What you do should work, though it may take some thought to convince oneself. I’d probably take it outside the for loop and guard it by `if (! added)` (to avoid inserting a letter already in there) and add it at index `size` (which should be the first available slot). Also beware of overflow: if `size` is already `MAX`, there’s no more room in your array.

> Would it be better to have my LetterList class on its own?

I was thinking the same. It’s a matter of taste, but I don’t really see a point in having it inside the `Letter` class.

You’re on the right track and you’re asking good questions.

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to answer my question and offer advice. I'll be implementing the changes you suggested and submitting my assignment. Have a great day.